# GCC looks for headers in /usr/local/include when compiling, but not for libraries in /usr/local/lib when linking. Why?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, header

I have installed in /usr/ the distribution provided version of SQLite - version 3.4.2.
I have installed in /usr/local/ SQLite version 3.7.4.

/usr/include/sqlite3.h defines SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER as 3004002
/usr/local/include/sqlite3.h defines SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER as 3007004

Version 3007004 has the function sqlite3_initialize(), version 3004002 does not.

```
$ nm -D /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so | grep sqlite3_initialize
00018e20 T sqlite3_initialize
```

When I compile the following example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

// This should fail if including /usr/include/sqlite3.h
#if SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER != 3007004
    #error "SQLite version is not 3.7.4"
#endif

int main() {
    printf( "%d\n", SQLITE_VERSION_NUMBER );
    sqlite3_initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and linked (with gcc 4.2.4) like this the preprocessor finds the sqlite3.h header for version 3.7.4 in /usr/local/include/, but the linker fails as it's looking in /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so for the symbols.

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o cpp -lsqlite3
/tmp/cc4iSSN6.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_initialize'
test.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `sqlite3_shutdown'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Of course I can specify the lib directory and it links the correct version of the library.

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lsqlite3
$ ./cpp
3007004
$
```

It seems by default gcc looks in /usr/local/include/ before /usr/include/ for headers, but not for libraries when linking. Why?

Edit 1: As suggested by Tim Post:

```
$ sudo ldconfig -n /usr/local/lib
$ ldconfig -p | grep sqlite3
    libsqlite3.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
    libsqlite3.so.0 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so.0
    libsqlite3.so (libc6) => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so
    libsqlite3.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libsqlite3.so
$ gcc -Wall cpp.c -o cpp -lsqlite3
/tmp/ccwPT9o0.o: In function `main':
cpp.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `sqlite3_initialize'
cpp.c:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `sqlite3_shutdown'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The include file search path is defined by *gcc*, but the library search path is encoded into *ld*, which is from a separate project; these are not necessarily synchronized.

One thing you could do is patch the *specs* file, which, if it exists, can be found in the same directory as *libgcc*; you can get the path to the latter using

```
gcc -print-libgcc-file-name
```

If there is no *specs* file there, create one using

```
gcc -dumpspecs >specs
```

and verify that gcc is reading it, by calling

```
gcc -v
```

Look for a line containing `%{L*}`, and add `-L/usr/local/lib` behind it (separated by spaces). Gcc will then pass this argument following any -L options from the command line to *ld* when linking.

In order to restore the defaults, just revert the specs file to its initial state (i.e. delete it if it didn't exist before).

Comment: The library paths are definitely specified on the `ld` command line by `gcc`, not just coded into `ld` (although they may also be coded into `ld`). Just use `strace` to see.

Answer (score 0):

This may be symptom of using the gold linker, which does not search `/usr/local/lib`, at least in some versions. Try removing the package `binutils-gold`.

Comment: -1 because removing gold, which is a much better linker, is not the best suggestion.

Comment: Then what is a better suggestion? Adding an explicit `-L/usr/local/lib` to all commandlines? For small projects, there is basically no difference between `gold` and `ld` except for this issue.

Comment: -1 because there is no difference between gold and ld regarding the search path. The link-time library search path comes from gcc.