# Why does C library link order only matter on some systems?

Tags: c, linker, dependencies, shared-libraries

My group developing a program which uses the JasPer library which depends on a JPEG library. My co-worker created a Makefile which listed the `-ljpeg` before `-ljasper` in the build rule. This worked fine on my co-worker's computer but would not build on mine:

```
$ make
cc  -DDEBUG compress_image_test.c -o compress_image_test -Wall -ljpeg -ljasper -lm -lcheck
/usr/local/lib/libjasper.a(jpg_dec.o): In function `jpg_decode':
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:158: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:159: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:162: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:165: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:168: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:190: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:197: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_dec.c:200: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/usr/local/lib/libjasper.a(jpg_enc.o): In function `jpg_encode':
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:284: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:285: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:288: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:294: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:310: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:314: undefined reference to `jpeg_default_colorspace'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:317: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:324: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:329: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
/cots/jasper-1.900.1/src/libjasper/jpg/jpg_enc.c:330: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [compress_image_test] Error 1
```

Both machines are running Ubuntu 12.04. The JasPer and JPEG libraries were built from source, not obtained through `apt-get`.

After reading another stack exchange post, [lib dependencies and their order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631316/lib-dependencies-and-their-order), I tried updating the makefile to swap the order of `-ljpeg` to after `-ljasper`. This worked.

So my question is, was the original order ok on another machine, which is basically equivalent to mine, but it did not work on my machine?

**May 5th Update:**

These are the relevant library files that I can find on my computer:

**/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Jun 21  2012 libjasper.so.1 -> libjasper.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 317148 Jan 11  2012 libjasper.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Nov 22 07:42 libjpeg.so.8 -> libjpeg.so.8.0.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284436 Nov 22 07:42 libjpeg.so.8.0.2
```

**/usr/local/lib:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1361856 May  2 09:14 libjasper.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     757 May  2 09:14 libjasper.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1461672 May  2 09:15 libjpeg.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     918 May  2 09:15 libjpeg.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 May  2 09:15 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.9.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 May  2 09:15 libjpeg.so.9 -> libjpeg.so.9.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  955739 May  2 09:15 libjpeg.so.9.1.0
```

And the same files as they exist on my co-workers computer:

**/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:**

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Oct 29  2013 libjasper.so.1 -> libjasper.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 317148 Jan 11  2012 libjasper.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Nov 22 07:42 libjpeg.so.8 -> libjpeg.so.8.0.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 284436 Nov 22 07:42 libjpeg.so.8.0.2
```

**/usr/local/lib:**

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1320124 Apr 24 16:01 libjasper.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     750 Apr 24 16:01 libjasper.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1462456 Apr 24 16:06 libjpeg.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     918 Apr 24 16:06 libjpeg.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 24 16:06 libjpeg.so -> libjpeg.so.9.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 24 16:06 libjpeg.so.9 -> libjpeg.so.9.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  955351 Apr 24 16:06 libjpeg.so.9.1.0
```

As far as I can see, all of the same files and links exist on the two systems.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably linking against a static library.

With dynamic libraries, the whole library is included in the link, which will make all of its symbols available to objects mentioned later, while for a static library, only those archive members that satisfy *currently* undefined symbols are linked, and the rest of the library ignored.

Comment: It's the same makefile on both computers. Is there something potentially different that would cause one to be using only the dynamic library somehow?

Comment: Dynamic libraries are preferred. If the dynamic library is not properly installed, it would cause a fallback on the static library.

Comment: I of course used the standard "configure / make / sudo make install" routine when building and installing the libraries. Is there anything to installing the libraries other than moving them to the library folder (in this case /usr/local/lib) ?

Comment: Is the `libjpeg.so` symlink present? That is what is actually used by the linker, and it should point to the fully versioned shared library.

Comment: The symlink is indeed present.

Comment: For some reason, the linker still believes it should use the static library (same as for libjasper, by the way -- you can see in the diagnostic output that it is using libjasper.a). I'd check that the symlink points to the correct file (if the symlink target does not exist, the linker will get the same error as if the symlink didn't exist, so there is no error message), and if it does, whether it is valid (`ldd` on that file should look sensible), and whether the user compiling the software does have read access.

Comment: I've updated the original question with what relavant library files I can find. I'd forgotten that there wasn't a jasper.so file in `/usr/local/lib`, but it doesn't seem to exist on either system. An ldd on `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1` seems to give sane output. I have sudoer access on my own system, but I'm not sure if that's what you meant with that final comment.

Comment: Okay, you have two different versions of libjpeg, that might become a problem if you build against the headers of one (in `/usr/include`) but link against the other (in `/usr/local/lib`). The other thing that may be the issue is that `/usr/local/lib` is not searched, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791699#4792089) for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

There is two possibilities for dynamic libraries:

1. If you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include path that in it `libjpeg.so` could be found, then `ld` will search in these paths for `libjpeg.so` automatically when it find out that `libjasper.so` needs it.
2. That `libjasper.so` may be built with a `-rpath` `ld` option. In this case, `ld` also will search in that path for dependent libraries automatically.

   You can find out whether there is a rpath in `libjasper.so` by `readelf -d /path/to/libjasper.so`.

Comment: When I log into my co-worker's computer with my own account local to the computer, I'm able to build it. My account does not have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to the path with libjpeg.so in it.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Oh, there is another possibility. That `libjasper.so` may include a RPATH, `ld` will also search that path for dependent libraries automatically. You can check that by `readelf -d /path/to/libjasper.so`.

Comment: Looks like JasPer itself does not use a dynamic library. The only files I see are /usr/local/lib/libjasper.a and /usr/local/lib/libjasper.la. I have confirmed my co-workers setup is the same.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Have you checked the JPEG library? Do you both use dynamic version? You also need to check whether those two `libjasper.a` in both machines need same external symbols?

Comment: We both installed the library the same way and we're both using the same Makefile. The make command is listed in the code block in the question. All of the files related to JasPer and JPEG in /usr/local/lib/ exist on both systems. I don't know how to explicitly tell the system to use dynamic libraries over static libraries or vice-versa.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Or you could simple switch the positions of `-ljpeg` and `-ljasper`.

Comment: Right, which is exactly what I'm doing but the whole question is why do I need to do it while my co-worker does not? Using readelf -d /usr/local/lib/jasper.a only seems to list the .o files that exist in the library file, not the dependencies.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber: Are you using the same compiler version, and the same linker version (`ld`)?  Have you compared your `/etc/ld.so.conf` files?  Did you both build the JPEG and Jasper libraries with the same configuration options?

Comment: Yes (gcc 4.6.3-1ubuntu5), yes (ld 2.22), and yes on the ld.so.conf files as well as the files in ld.so.conf.d. Except for my co-worker has a file called x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf with the contents '/etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf'. Don't know if that maters.